# How can I separate PAM authorization for login from sudo (using Duo)?

Tags: sudo, pam, authentication, 2-factor-authentication

I recently installed Duo on an Ubuntu test server using these instructions: https://duo.com/docs/duounix

While 2FA authentication for login works as expected, I was not expecting every use of `sudo` to also require 2FA. I only want to use 2FA (Duo + ssh key) for actually logging in, and then use sudo with a typed password as before.

From what I have read, the answer probably lies in `/etc/pam.d/`, but I feel pretty clueless about exactly what changes to make. My  experiments with editing these files have resulted in my being locked out of using `sudo`.

Comment: Did you edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`?

Comment: Yes, as per the Ubuntu 20.04 instructions I linked to.

Comment: That file contains, as the name says, common authentication modules. The PAM configuration for `sudo` includes it. So, either: make those changes in the specific PAM configuration files you want to affect instead of in `common-auth`, or copy the previous common content in `common-auth` to `sudo`s PAM configuration and remove the include.

Comment: I have commented out everything in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and that makes no difference. I think I am unclear on how to change the PAM configuration for sudo.

Comment: OK so as usual I turned out I simply had not read the linked docs carefully enough. By simply changing `common-auth` back to the original as suggested by @muru, but configuring sshd_config as described in the docs, Duo now only is needed for the ssh login.